# C# Jagged Array, determine if any pair matches

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, comparison

In the code below I am populating a Jagged array full of keys(properties) in an object:

```
  foreach (var item in Items.Where(x => x.NeedsSaved))
        {
            int[][] valuePairs = new int[item.Collection.Count()][];

            int i = 0;

            foreach (var collectionItem in item.Collection)
            {
                valuePairs[i] = new int[4] { collectionItem.Id1, collectionItem.Id2, collectionItem.Id3, collectionItem.Id4};
                i++;
            }
                 -- TODO
         }

        return false;
```

I am trying to determine if any duplicate key pairs exist. I'm sure there is something easy I am missing with Linq. Every pair of 4 values needs to be unique, so If I have a collection of two in the array that are equal to :

{1, 1, 1, 1}
and
{1, 1, 1, 1}

The method should return true.

but if the values are
{1, 1, 1, 1}
{2, 1, 1, 1}

The method should return false.

To add further clarification, the purpose is that when saving in a Client, I am posting to the API. This object has a compound primary key of (a, b, c, d) so I am trying to warn the user by validation before the API is hit,  causing a duplicate key exception.

I appreciate any help, and if this is a duplicate I apologize, I tried searching as best as I could for an answer.

Comment: Why use a jagged array at all? It would be easier to use a custom class to store the four integer values and define an EqualityComparer on that class.

Comment: This is something I hadn't thought of and sounds like a great idea. I'm going to implement it now and I will update this question once I have tested everything. Thank you!

Comment: `Enumerable.SequenceEqual` would probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Xaver's suggestion, I realized that using a Jagged array made things more complicated.

I ended up using the IEquatable interface, and the solution ended up looking like this:

```
   private bool HasDuplicateKeyValues()
    {
        foreach (var item in Items.Where(x => x.NeedsSaved))
        {
            List<KeyValues> keyPairs = new List<KeyValues>();

            foreach (var collectionItem in item.Collection)
            {
                keyPairs.Add(new KeyValues(collectionItem.Id1, collectionItem.Id2, collectionItem.Id3, collectionItem.Id4));
            }

            foreach (var kp in keyPairs)
            {
                if (keyPairs.Where(x => x.Equals(kp)).Count() > 1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class KeyValues : IEquatable<KeyValues>
{
    public int Id1 { get; set; }
    public int Id2 { get; set; }
    public int Id3 { get; set; }
    public int Id4 { get; set; }

    public KeyValues(int id1, int id2, int id3, int id4)
    {
        Id1 = id1;
        Id2 = id2;
        Id3 = id3;
        Id4 = id4;
    }

    public bool Equals(KeyValues other)
    {
        return this.Id1 == other.Id1 && this.Id2 == other.Id2 && this.Id3 == other.Id3 && this.Id4 == other.Id4;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So in fact you have an array  `Items`. Every `Item` is an array of integers.

You want to know whether the sequence of `Items` are "equal".

Your definition of equal is not the standard definition. If we want to have a reusable non-standard notion of equality, we have to write an `IEqualityComparer<int[][]>`.

This is similar to all the versions of `IEqualityComparer<string>` to compare two strings. There is the default string comparer, but also an OrdinalIgnoreCase, InvariantCulture, etc. You could even create your own, for instance one that ignores white spaces.

Once you've written the `IEqualityComparer<int[][]>`, usage would be like:

```
IEqualityComparer<int[][]> comparer = ...
int[][] x = ...
int[][] y = ...
bool equal = comparer.Equals(x, y);
```

Quite often an Equality Comparer is derived from class `EqualityComparer<T>`

### Equality Comparer for int[]

Let's first write an EqualityComparer for `int[]`:

`int[] x` and `int[] y` are equal have they have the same length, and for every `0<i<length x[i] == y[i]`.

```
public class IntArrayComparer : EqualityComparer<int[]>
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<int[]> ByValue {get;} = new ArrayByValueComparer();

    public override bool Equals (int[] x, int[] y)
    {
        // for efficiency reasons, start every EqualityComparer with the same three lines
        if (x == null) return y == null;   // true if both null;
                                           // false if x null and y not null
        if (y == null) return false;       // false, because x not null
        if (object.ReferenceEqual(x, y) return true;:

        // do the actual equality check:
        return x.Length == y.Length && x.SequenceEqual(y);

        // or use the alternative without LINQ
        if (x.Length != y.Length) return false;
        for (int i=0; i<x.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (x[i] != y[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode (int[] x)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IEqualityComparer<int[]> comparer = IntArrayComparer.ByValue;
int[] x = ...
int[] y = ...
bool equal = comparer.Equals(x, y);
```

### Intermezzo GetHashCode

You only need the GetHashCode if you will be using it in structures where a fast lookup is needed, like a Dictionary or a HashSet. The purpose of GetHashCode is to have a very fast way to detect that two items are different. Not to detect that they are equal!

For example, if you have Customers, each Customer with a CustomerId, and you detect that `x.CustomerId != y.CustomerId`, then you can be certain that Customer x is not equal to Customer y. However, if they have the same Id, you cannot be certain if all values are equal.

So the only requirement for GetHashCode is: "if, according to your definition of equality x equals y, then x.GetHashCode() should return the same value as y.GetHashCode().

If x not equal to y, then we don't know whether they are equal or different. Different objects may return the same HashCode. This can easily be seen by `Int64.GetHashCode()`. As the return value is an `Int32`, there must be several `Int64` values that have the same hash code.

For Customer addresses: if you have seen that the Post code is different, you know that the Customers live at different addresses. So after checking the Post codes only of a sequence of Customer Addresses, you may have thrown away 99.9% of the Customers, you only need to check the last 0.1%

A good hash code is such that it detects differences for most instances of your class fast. For the hash code you don't have to check all values of your array, only the ones that are an indication of being different.

So in this case, for the HashCode, let's only check the length and the first element.

```
public override int GetHashCode (int[] x)
{
    if (x ==  null) return 658779956;

    return x.Length.GetHashCode() * 77852364 + x[0].GetHashCode();
}
```

If  most of your inner arrays will have the same length, then it is no use to use the Length to calculate the HashCode. Test the properties that are most likely to be different.

Advise: I usually don't implement GetHashCode. If later the Comparer is used in lookup structures like a Dictionary, then you get the exeception. You can implement GetHashCode then.

### Back to your question

Now that we have seen how to create an equality comparer for `int[]`, it is easy to create one for `int[][]`.

```
class JaggedIntArrayComparer : EqulityComparer<int[][]>
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<int[][]> ByValue {get;} = new JaggedIntArrayComparer();

    // use the previously created Equality Comparer
    private static IEqualityComparer<int[]> IntArrayComparer {get;} = IntArryComparer.ByValue;

    public override bool Equals (int[][] x, int[][] y)
    {
         // The same three lines as in the previous comparer:
         if (x == null) return y == null;
         if (y == null) return false;
         if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

         return x.Length == y.Length && x.SequenceEqual(y, IntArrayComparer);

         // alternative without LINQ, similar to the previous comparer
         if (x.Length != y.Length) return false;
         for (int i=0; i< x.Length; ++i)
         {
             if (!IntArrayComparer.Equals(x[i], yi[])) return false;
         }
         return true;
    }

    // TODO: invent a simple GetHashCode;
}
```